# How to select vertical bar?

Tags: oracle

I want to select vertical bar from oracle. for example,

my query is `select '123' || ' | 456' from dual` and expecting output is

'123 | 456'.

```
select '123' || ' | 456' from dual
```

Comment: my query is run in stored procedure in dynamic query. for example, v_sql := ' select '123' || ' | 456' from dual '; but in doesn't work

Comment: That is not running a query, it is attempting to assign a string value to a variable, and that (query) string contains single quotes. It would help if your question said exactly what you are doing, what you are trying to achieve, and the errors you get. It doesn't look like you actually want a query, but it's really hard to tell...

Comment: The real question is in your Comment, not in the original post. To answer your question (from the Comment): If your string contains single-quotes, you must **escape** them. You must use **two consecutive single-quotes** to generate a single single-quote in the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

The fault, to misquote the bard, is not in our vertical bars but in our single quotes.

You need to double up the quotes which are internal to the query string so you get a single quote character in the string:

```
v_sql := 'select ''123'' || '' | 456'' from dual';
```

After this line executes `v_sql` will have the value

```
select '123' || ' | 456' from dual
```

which you can then execute and get as a result

```
123 | 456
```